# Unable to save file after recovery from backup

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share, backup-restoration

I have a Windows Server 2003 that acts as the file server. I have moved a lot of files from a backup (different domain) to the new shares.

The strange thing is that people can open the files, but they can't save over it. Then it asks for a new filename (no overwrite).

I have tried to take ownership as administrator, and removing the read-only (gray) checkbox from the folder (incl. subfolders and files).

Someone knows what to do?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your NTFS ACLs are incorrect. What *I* would do (which may work for you or may not, I'm not guaranteeing anything) would be this:

- Edit the properties for the folder containing the files, and set the permissions to what I want them to be
- Go into the Advanced section, and tick the "Replace permissions on child items" box
  Click OK and wait while the permissions are updated

This will reset the permissions on everything inside the parent folder to be whatever the parent folder is. This answer does assume you know about NTFS permissions, if not then I would suggest reading up on them first so that you're comfortable with the concept.

Comment: I tried that. But it failed. Now I did the following and it works.. Properties of the folder holding the files, security tab, advance settings, uncheck the Allow inhereritable permissions, apply. And then do the thing you described above, then check the Allow inhereritable permissions again.... very.. very.. strange...